# Check and run correct Tensorflow Version (v2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, version, tensorflow2.0

i was using the previous version of tensorflow, but i wanna use tensorflow 2.0.0 alpha and i've installed it with pip using

```py
    pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0
```

than i run the simple code to check what version

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    print(tf.__version__)
```

but this is the result:

```
1.13.0-rc1
```

so i check with pip

```py
    pip3 show tensorflow
```

and i got:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.0.0a0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for 
everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: 
c:\users\massimo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: gast, six, protobuf, google-pasta, absl-py, astor, tb-nightly, 
termcolor, grpcio, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, tf-estimator- 
nightly, wheel, numpy
Required-by:
```

is there something wrong? i'm expecting with tf.**version** something like 2.0.0

what i'm missing?

Thank you all

Max

UPDATE

while the command

```
python -m site


sys.path = [
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppVisualCode',
 'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37. 
  zip',
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site- 
   packages',
  ]
  USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (exists)
  USER_SITE: 
   'C:\\Users\\Massimo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages' 
  (exists)
  ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: Most likely you have multiple python interpreters installed. Check the output of `where python` if it points to the one in `c:\users\massimo\appdata\local\programs\python`

Comment: Maybe it should rather be `pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 `?

Comment: the pip3 command give me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

if you have two interpreters both with python version 3+ upgrade your pip to version 0.8 or above for both the interpreters and then you can also do this

```
pip3.5 install package1
pip3.6 install package2
pip3.7 install package3
```

I was about to write the same answer as what Vlad wrote in the comment but because it didn't work for you & since you are already using multiple python interpreters,

another possible suggestion could be to use them in a different virtual environment (interpreters with different or same python versions) for all your new projects (it's also highly recommended by most of the Data Scientists).

After that install the packages with exact version that you want to use and you'll be good to go. You'll never have to worry about for which interpreter/environment you installed which package.